# Retorno Null Print Java

Tags: java, array, null

Estou desenvolvendo um exercício em que preciso criar uma classe `Ponto` e adicionar a um Array de pontos sem que eu use `ArrayList`, ao testar a 1ª opção que há no menu recebi um retorno de que o array estava **`Null`** mesmo que eu já tivesse adicionado um objeto ponto nele.

Este é meu primeiro código em Java e não sei bem a estrutura ainda.

Os arquivos estão todos no mesmo Packages.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tam;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite por favor o tamanho da colecao :");
        tam = input.nextInt();
        ListaPonto lista = new ListaPonto();
        lista.listap(tam);
        while(true) {
            int opc;
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n");
            System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\nProjeto Colecao de Elementos");
            System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n0 - Encerrar");
            System.out.println("\n1 - Adicionar um elemento no Final");
            System.out.println("\n2 - Adicionar um elemento em uma posição");
            System.out.println("\n3 - Retornar indice da primeira ocorrencia de um elemento");
            System.out.println("\n4 - Remover um elemento em uma posicao");
            System.out.println("\n5 - Calcular a distantia dos 2 pontos mais distantes");
            System.out.println("\n6 - Colecao de pontos contidos em um Circulo");
            System.out.println("\n\n Informe sua opcao :");
            opc = input.nextInt();
        
            if(opc == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if(opc == 1) {
                Ponto p = new Ponto();
                int x,y;
                System.out.println("\nDigite o x do Ponto :");
                x = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\nDigite o y do Ponto :");
                y = input.nextInt();
                p.pontos(x, y);
                lista.adiciona(p);
                lista.printa();         
            }
    
        }
    }   
}
```

Aqui a Classe Ponto é criada

```
public class Ponto{
    private int x,y;

    public int pontos(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    return x;
    }

}
```

A Classe da Lista é Criada Aqui.

```
public class ListaPonto{
    private Ponto pontos[];
    private int validos;
    private int topo;


    public void listap(int N) {
        topo = N;
        this.pontos = new Ponto[N];
        this.validos = 0;   
    } 


    public void printa() {
        for (int i =0;i<=0;i++) {
            System.out.println(this.pontos[i]);
        }
    }


    public void adiciona(Ponto elem) {
        this.pontos[topo-1] = elem; 
    }


}
```

Comment: Não vi todos os erros, mas uma coisa que vc podia fazer é criar construtores nas classes (por exemplo, na classe `Ponto`, em vez de ter o método `pontos`, crie um construtor que recebe `x` e `y` - o mesmo vale para o método `listap`). Veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052)

Answer (score 1):

Quando você inicializa um array de elementos não primitivos em Java, todas as posições são preenchidas com null. Assim, quando você executa este método:

```
lista.listap(tam);
```

Você está inicializando seu array `pontos`. Se neste momento, você o percorresse e printasse o conteúdo de cada posição dele, você teria algo assim:

```
null
null
null
...
```

A opção 1 do seu programa diz:

```
System.out.println("\n1 - Adicionar um elemento no Final");
```

Quando você executa a linha `lista.adiciona(p);`, seu programa adiciona no fim do array o ponto criado. Se você printasse novamente esse array agora, você teria algo assim:

```
null
null
null
seu ponto aqui
```

Porém, seu método `printa()` tem um erro:

```
for (int i =0;i<=0;i++) {
```

Veja que, da forma que está, você está dizendo que é para o `for` se encerrar quando `i<=0`. Ora, se `i` é inicializado com `0`, isso significa que ele vai imprimir apenas o conteúdo da primeira posição do seu array, que, como expliquei antes, tem o conteúdo `null`, afinal, neste momento você tem apenas a última posição preenchida com o ponto que você criou.

Para que você imprima todas as posições do array, seu `for` deve ser:

```
for (int i =0;i<topo;i++) {
```

ou, melhor ainda:

```
for (int i =0;i<this.pontos.length;i++) {
```

Pois isso garante que todas as posições do array serão impressas.

Answer (score 0):

Eu aconselharia a criar um construtor para Pontos com os parâmetros x e y.
Da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Ponto {
private int x,y;

public Ponto(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

E ao criar o objeto, espere os valores do console

```
int x,y;
System.out.println("\nDigite o x do Ponto :");
x = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("\nDigite o y do Ponto :");
y = input.nextInt();
Ponto p = new Ponto(x, y);
lista.adiciona(p);
lista.printa();
```